# AWS NodeJS SDK: intermittent AllAccessDisabled error in S3, UnrecognizedClientException in Dynamo

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Using the AWS-SDK (v 2.27.0) in NodeJS, I have a function that creates a new record in a dynamo table, and then saves two files to different folders in an S3 bucket. Both dynamo and S3 are located in eu-west-2.

Generally speaking, my function succeeds. However, roughly one in ten times I get a failure of some sort. This happens with either the dynamo (save) process, or the S3 (putItem) process.

Here are details of the errors, and the code that triggers them:

**Dynamo**

Error Message: `Error saving: UnrecognizedClientException: No account found for the given parameters`

```js
// [...]
let params = {
  TableName: 'users',
  Item: data, //json object
  ReturnValues: 'NONE'
};

dynamo.putItem(params, function(err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    deferred.reject(err);
  }
  else {
    deferred.resolve(data.data.S); // successful response
  }
});
```

I then tried to run the process again (without changing anything) about five minutes later, and this time the dynamo record saved correctly, without the above error. However, I then saw an error in saving to S3.

**S3 Issue**

Error Message: `AllAccessDisabled: All access to this object has been disabled`

```js
s3.putObject({
  Key: 'public/'+id+'.pem',
  Body: pair[keyType] //string
}).promise().then(function() {
  deferred.resolve();
},
function(err) {
  console.log(err);
  deferred.reject();
});
```

---

I find it very odd that it is sometimes working and sometimes not, which makes me wonder if it is something wrong with the AWS account? I sometimes see errors "All access to this object has been disabled" when browsing my S3 bucket through the AWS dashboard as well.

Here is how I initialise AWS/S3/Dynamo

```js
AWS.config.update({
  region: 'eu-west-2'
});
const s3 = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'universalapikeys', region: 'eu-west-2'}});
const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB({region: 'eu-west-2'});
```

The secret and key come from two env vars, `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, and in my understanding are utilised by the aws-sdk automatically. My IAM user has AmazonS3FullAccess and AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess attached directly (amongst others).

Comment: You have two different services intermittently giving you error messages that seem to be telling you that AWS is actively engaged in the process of suspending or terminating the services on your account.  Have you checked your account page, checked your billing and payment history, and checked the email account you used when signing up for correspondence, to see whether perhaps there's information in one of those places that might explain what you're seeing?

Comment: Thanks Michael - although nothing obvious seems wrong with billing details and the account is not indicated as being suspended/terminated. Raised a ticket with AWS Support and still waiting to hear a response though. I'll update here if I find any resolution.

Comment: Hi Josh, did you (or AWS Support) find a solution to this problem? We're seeing similar errors intermittently, and I'm trying to find some more information ...

Comment: Hi darph, I am sorry - in the end we just closed the AWS account and used an existing one that we had.